# Oracle linked server super slow

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 which has Oracle as a linked server.

If I run a simple query directly on Oracle:

```
select *
from Server..TableA 
where Name like 'Jack%'
```

it takes 0.9 seconds.

Doing the same thing from the SQL Server takes 2 minutes!

Is this a known issue and any ideas on how to fix this?

Is response to below solution if `OpenQuery` is always far faster than `..Servername`. Why does the second method even exist?

Comment: How many rows does the query return?  Are you measuring the time required to get the first row or the last row in both instances?  Have you looked at `v$sql` to see what query is actually being run in Oracle via the linked server?

Comment: only 120 rows.  No idea how to use v$sql. please elaborate.

Comment: `v$sql` shows every query in Oracle's cache.  If you search for your SQL text, you should be able to find the query that is actually being sent and then can link that to the plan, execution statistics, etc.  My wild guess is that the predicate is being applied on the SQL Server side rather than the Oracle side.  Possibly because of a character set issue but that's starting to get quite speculative.  The first step would be to determine what Oracle is actually seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do not answer my question but since this slowness wasted several hours
of my time and I finally found a solution I will post it here.
Hope this saves few hours of someone else life :)

The solution is to use TSQL OpenQuery function:

For example

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (OracleSvr, 'SELECT name FROM joe.titles WHERE name = ''NewTitle''');
```

In my experience so far OpenQuery is really fast!